# how to reduce server response time

Tags: joomla-3.x, performance, server-response-time, wpo

How should i improve my site's server response time?
[image]

on gtmetrix waterfall tab shows that my site spends 2.8 seconds on requesting part
how can i reduce this part's duration?
[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you read the section where it says: "Please read our documentation to learn how you can monitor and measure where you server is spending the most time"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently reduced the server wait time on a client website from over 5 seconds to about a third of a second.

**What didn't help**

Enabling the Joomla cache would probably have helped but this often causes issues for me with CAPTCHA's not working etc.

I tried the free version of [JCH Optimise](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jch-optimize) to combine CSS and JavaScript files but there was very little improvement on this particular website (your mileage may vary).

**What did help**

Apart from all the usual steps such as reducing the number of third party extensions, finding the fastest third party extensions, enabling GZip etc, there were two things that really helped:

**1. Reducing the number of modules that are loaded**

There were a few places where I was able to reduce the number of modules I was loading.

For example, I was able to combine several modules in the footer area (social sharing buttons, a footer menu, a copyright notice and developer credit, member signup and login buttons and a logo) into one Custom HTML module.

I used [responsive classes supplied with the template](http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/basic/creating_responsive_content.md#custom-responsive-grids) so that the columns still worked well responsively.

I was able to use the same trick in another area of the template, reducing three modules into one.

This helped reduce the server wait time by a couple of seconds.

**2. Upgraded Hosting**

The website was still too slow, so I convinced the client to upgrade their SiteGround "Startup" hosting account to the "GrowBig" account which includes an option to [enable dynamic cache](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/supercacher/dynamic_cache/).

Once dynamic cache was enabled, the server wait time reduced to under a second.

I am using dynamic cache on all my own websites and quite a few client websites and dynamic cache does not seem to interfere with CAPTCHA's etc or cause any other issues and I am using quite a range of different extensions.

I'm sure there are other improvements that can help but this is what worked for me.

Comment: thank a lot for your help.. i contacted my host company. they said they have dynamic cache enabled. now i should find and download the plugin. can u please give me the download link of the plugin that u used?

Comment: See the "enable dynamic cache" link in the answer above for the instructions I used

Comment: my host company doesn't provide the plugin :/ . they said i have to find it myself

Comment: I think this is likely specific to the hosting company so the SiteGround dynamic cache plugin will be useless to you unless you are hosting with SiteGround.

Comment: i would be so appreciated if u email me the siteground plugin.. idk if its ok with stackexchange to leave my email address in comments. "e.kiasati[atSign]gmail.com"

Comment: You can download the plugin from: http://download.siteground.com/jSGCache.zip although as I already stated, I think this is specific to SiteGround hosting.

Comment: as you said and i thought, it didn't work. i just wanted to try it. i think my host company doesn't have the "dynamic cache" function. i guess i should combine modules now. thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also fine tune a lot with JCH Optimze Pro that will make a lot of improvement for speed. and also optimze your htaccess file for example with akeeba Admin Pro if you dont know how to optimimze your htaccess file for speed and security

Comment: I'm using RSfirewall now. r u suggesting that i should uninstall rsfirewall and install akeeba admin pro?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

when i was uninstalling the jCGcache plugin, i saw "System - Page Cache" 
i enabled it and BOOM, Problem solved. 
server response time improved 2 seconds, and now it's under one second.

THANKS TO Neil Robertson FOR HELPING AND TELLING ME ABOUT CACHING.

Comment: Wow! That solved my issue instantly also. Nice tip - thanks